# Not able to use BeautifulSoup to get span content of Nasdaq100 future

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 
import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

 url = 'www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/NQU18'
 r  = requests.get("https://" +url)

 data = r.text
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
 price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'last-change',
                   'data-ng-class': "highlightValue('priceChange’)”}).text

 print(price)
```

**Result:**

```
[[ item.priceChange ]]
```

It is not the span content. The result should be price. Where am I going wrong?

**The following is the span tag of the page:**

[image]

**2nd screenshot:** How can I get the time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'up'}).text` instead to get the `+X.XX` value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/NQU18'
r = requests.get("https://" +url)

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'up'}).text

print(price)
```

Output currently is:

```
+74.75
```

The `tradeTime` you seek seems to not be present in the page_source, since it's dynamically generated through JavaScript. You can, however, find it elsewhere if you're a little clever, and use the `json` library to parse the JSON data from a certain script element:

```
import json
trade_time = soup.find('script', {"id": 'barchart-www-inline-data'}).text
json_data = json.loads(trade_time)
print(json_data["NQU18"]["quote"]["tradeTime"])
```

This outputs:

`2018-06-14T18:14:05`

If these don't solve your problem then you will have to resort to something like Selenium that can run JavaScript to get what you're looking for:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = ("https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/NQU18")
driver.get(url)
result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-content-column"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]/span[1]')
print(result.text)
```

Currently the output is:

```
-13.00
```

Comment: It works. thank you. Why I am getting [[ item.priceChange ]], which is child of span class 'up'? Is it because I am trying to get child of class 'up', which is dynamically updated?

Comment: If you print out `price` in full you'll see it is `<span class="last-change" data-ng-class="highlightValue('priceChange')">[[ item.priceChange ]]</span>`, so it seems that that's what's going on. I'm not sure why it's doing that though because I haven't encountered this before. Been looking around but can't figure it out.

Comment: Not sure why getting [[ item.priceChange ]]. For following 2 span, how to get time from it?  <span class="symbol-trade-time" data-ng-class="highlightValue('tradeTime')">17:09 CT</span>
<span class="symbol-trade-time">[GBLX]</span>. I can only get: unicode: [[ item.tradeTime ]] with both trade_time = soup.find('span', {'class': 'symbol-trade-time'}).text
trade_time = soup.find('span', {'class': 'symbol-trade-time',
                                'data-ng-class': "highlightValue('tradeTime')"}).text

Comment: I added to my answer to address this new question of yours. By the way, if you find an answer solved your problem, you should consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yes. Solved my original posted question. BTW, I added 2nd image that has 2 spans, but I can't get time from one of the tag. Your post is to find and get time from whole page. That's not what I am looking for. We still don't know why getting  [[ item.priceChange ]] and [[ item.tradeTime ]]. Thank you so much.

Comment: So like I said, that content is being dynamically generated using a particular JavaScript file. If you really want that content you'll need to be able to run JavaScript, possibly using something like Selenium, or PyQt5.

Comment: price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'up'}) becomes price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'down'}) to mark price direction with different color. It's not unique depending on day. So, this does not solve the problem. Have to use class="highlightValue('priceChange')" to get price, which is unique. But, it gets '[[ item.priceChange ]]'. Not sure what it is.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of using something like Selenium to run the JavaScript that's producing the elements you're looking for. It's far slower than requests, so it depends on how often you plan on scraping this information. You should just see if the site has an API that you can use instead.